# Creating a priority queue in C using strings

Tags: c, queue, priority-queue

NOTE: the code snippets may not work its for demonstration the idea on my head.

I am trying to copy the bank queues in c but very basic. I am new to C and I am really looking for help in here.

So I want 3 main tasks to happen.

1. Inserting Customer.
2. Removing Customer.
3. Showing list of the customers in queue.

For `1` I came up with this idea:

```c
int pri_que[MAX];
int front, rear;

void insert(char data){

    if (rear >= MAX - 1){

        printf("\nQueue is full.");
        return;
    }

    if ((front == -1) && (rear == -1)){

        front++;
        rear++;
        pri_que[rear] = data;
        return;
    }    

    else{

        check(data);
    }
    rear++;

}
```

then I have the `check` function

```c
void check(char data) {

    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i <= rear; i++) {

        if (data >= pri_que[i]) {

            for (j = rear + 1; j > i; j--) {

                pri_que[j] = pri_que[j - 1];

            }

            pri_que[i] = data;
            return;
        }
    }
    pri_que[i] = data;
}
```

The `del` function

```c
void del(char data) {

    int i;

    if ((front==-1) && (rear==-1)) {

        printf("\nQueue is empty ");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= rear; i++) {

        if (data == pri_que[i]) {
            
            for (; i < rear; i++) {

                pri_que[i] = pri_que[i + 1];
            }

        pri_que[i] = -99;

        rear--;

        if (rear == -1)
            front = -1;

        return;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d not found in queue to delete", data);
}
```

And finally the `show` function.

```c
void show() {
    if ((front == -1) && (rear == -1)) {

        printf("\nQueue is empty");
        return;

    }
    
    for (; front <= rear; front++) {
        
        printf(" %d ", pri_que[front]);
    }
    
    front = 0;
}
```

By the way I want to show the waiting customers like this:

```
1 - James
2 - Jacop
3 - Sarah
```

Comment: So, how many priorities do you think to use? For example will be there a MAXIMUM priority level say 10?

Comment: MAX_SIZE 10 is good

Comment: You don't even have a main code for me to know what algorithm you want to implement exactly. How do you want to prioritize the names actually? E.g. in the main you ask for prioritization with a name entered or just queue it in ascending order? More details make you get more help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is what you want.

```
Please enter 10 names with priorities
1) priority and name: 2 name-1
2) priority and name: 5 name-2
3) priority and name: 6 name-3              
4) priority and name: 7 name-4
5) priority and name: 8 name-5
6) priority and name: 9 name-6
7) priority and name: 10 name-7
8) priority and name: 1 name-8
9) priority and name: 3 name-9
10) priority and name: 4 name-10

Priority        Name
2       name-1
5       name-2
6       name-3
7       name-4
8       name-5
9       name-6
10      name-7
1       name-8
3       name-9
4       name-10
```

This is the code that you can use to create strings and insert them to the queue. Then you can develop rest of the functions by inspiring this sample code that I have written for the your purpose. If you have any trouble while developing upon this sample code just ask me to resolve the issue. Good luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10

struct item {
    int priority;
    char *name;
};

int front=0,rear=0;
struct item priQueue[MAX];

char *getMemoryFor(const char *ch){
    char *mem = malloc(strlen(ch) * sizeof(char));
    return mem;
}

void insert(int priority, const char *data){

    if (rear > MAX){
        printf("\nQueue is full.\n");
        return;
    }

    priQueue[rear].priority = priority;
    char *loc = getMemoryFor(data);
    if(loc == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        return; // No memory so don't continue
    }
    strcpy(loc, data); // Copy the name to the allocated location
    priQueue[rear].name = loc; // Store the location of the name in the queue
    rear++;
}

void show(){
    if ((front == -1) && (rear == -1)){

        printf("\nQueue is empty\n");
        return;

    }
    
    printf("\nPriority\tName\n");
    for (; front < rear; front++){
        
        printf("%d\t%s\n", priQueue[front].priority, priQueue[front].name);
    }
    
    front = 0;
}

int main() {
    
    printf("Please enter 10 names with priorities\n");
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        int pri = 0;
        char nameTemp[50];
        printf("%d) priority and name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d%s", &pri, nameTemp);
        insert(pri, nameTemp);
    }
    
    show();
  
}
```